# Will Html5 multi select control works on ipad?? If possible any special attribute to add to select tag?

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, safari, multi-select

I want to use Html5 multi-select in my application which should work on ipad(safari). Will the present multi-select works on ipad??
If not do we need to add any attribute to make it work on ipad

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) this feature works in Safari well, you only have to provide a `multiple` argument to the `<select>` tag

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```